# How to fix blank page in IIS

Tags: iis

I'm getting a blank page with no error, when go to http://loclahost, the IIS server is working, and static content is enabled.

Comment: According to your description, Firstly , you mean http://localhost not  http://loclahost right? Then , http://localhost could only show the site which port is 80,I suggest that you could check the bindings of the site , in normal the default  site  port is 80,if the port of bindings has changed, it couldn't show the content. Else I suggest that you could check the default document for the web site. The list order is important and it wll serve the first page it finds in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the issue had to do with IIS, a reinstall fixed my issue